# I tried to write code in startActivity.java, but showing error while build

Tags: java, android

```
private Button mRegBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    mRegBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.start _reg_btn);
    mRegBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent reg_intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
             startActivity(reg_intent);

        }
    });



    }
```

This one showing in red color and failed to find "start _reg_btn"

and showing like below

```
null    
G:/HELLOWORLD   
app/src/main/java   
com/example/helloworld/StartActivity.java   
error: ')' expected 
error: illegal start of expression
```

Comment: what red colour ? Logcat ? error description ? Expected results ? Description of the problem ? What are you trying to do ? Explain yourself. take the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Format your question so it can be read without difficulty or pain..

Comment: i added error description sir please tell me the problem, that "start_reg_btn" text showing in red color

Comment: **R.id.start _reg_btn** cannot have a **space** in it. Neither on **Java** or **XLM** side.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between `start_reg_btn` and verify your Button Id in your xml file which same or not.

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="125dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="125dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="252dp"
        android:text="@string/need_a_new_account" />
</RelativeLayout>        above is the xml file of my button sir

Comment: mRegBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.textView); write this. Your problem solve.

Comment: i removed space sir, but showing like, can not resolve symbol start_reg_btn

Comment: just change button ID in your java code. **start_reg_btn ** to  **R.id.textView** You pass wrong ID of button which is not available in your xml file. So, try this.

Comment: i changed like this sir,  android:id="@+id/start_reg_btn", now it's cleared thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help you. Happy coding.

Comment: Because in xml the id of button is textView and in java start_reg_btn